# Why does ChromeDriver keep logging to console?

Tags: selenium, logging, selenium-chromedriver, log4j2

I have a Java project that uses selenium and ChromeDriver to automate testing on my website. I have log4j2 and slf4j configured for my logging files. The driver however refuses to log into my files and uses the console instead:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41) on port 41019
Only local connections are allowed.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Apr 20, 2018 12:31:42 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

**What do I have to tweak in my logging settings so that the web driver logs into my logging files and not to console?** My knowledge about logging is limited, sorry. An explanation what I did wrong would be appreciated.

I tried the following appenders in my log4j2.xml:

```
<logger name="org.openqa.selenium" level="all">
    <AppenderRef ref="selenium"/>
</logger>
<logger name="webdriver.chrome" level="all">
    <AppenderRef ref="webdriverChrome"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies" level="all">
    <AppenderRef ref="webdriverChrome"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.seleniumhq.selenium.selenium-chrome-driver" level="all">
    <AppenderRef ref="webdriverChrome"/>
</logger>
```

My maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.22</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.22</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.24</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials to generate `log4j2` and `slf4j` log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this half baked solution. Use this code when you initialize the web/chrome driver:

```
  Properties log4jProp = new Properties();
  log4jProp.setProperty("log4j.rootLogger", "WARN");
  PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jProp);

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logFile", ".//log//webdriverChrome_1.log");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(waitInMilliseconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

It only removes the warning for the logging framework. I am satisfied to a degree. If anyone knows the answer to get the rest of the console message into a logger would be appreciated.

The result so far:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41) on port 41019
Only local connections are allowed.
Apr 20, 2018 12:31:42 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```